# How to obtain the positions of the points in a lattice

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I want to know the positions of each point in a hexagon lattice, like
[image: Points using Graphics]

I saw some posts where they obtain this lattice using a function

```
pts[x_, y_] := 
  Flatten[Table[{{3 m, \[Sqrt]3 n}, {3 m + 3/2, \[Sqrt]3 n + \[Sqrt]3/
       2}}, {m, 0, x}, {n, 0, y}], 2];
```

And then, converting these points into a lattice, with Polygon, and Points.

```
Hexagon = {EdgeForm[Thickness[0.01]], Yellow, 
   Polygon[Table[{Cos[n Pi/3], Sin[n Pi/3]}, {n, 6}]], 
   PointSize[0.02], Black, 
   Point /@ Table[{Cos[n Pi/3], Sin[n Pi/3]}, {n, 6}]};
Graphics[Translate[Hexagon, pts[3, 2]]]
```

But if you look to the function pts[x,y] in ListPlot it doesn't give to you a hexagon lattice pattern.

How can I exhibit a hexagon lattice using ListPlot, and get the {x,y} points? And after that, how can I rotate these points by Pi/2?

Obs; I tried to find some logic using the hexagon geometry. Defining the distance of the nearest points by `a0` the second nearest distance between the points will be `Sqrt[3] a0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the OP, the hexagon shape is defined by these points (inside `Polygon` in the example):

```
hexpoints = Table[{Cos[n Pi/3], Sin[n Pi/3]}, {n, 6}]

(* {{1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {-(1/2), Sqrt[3]/2}, {-1, 0}, {-(1/2), -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, {1/2, -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, {1, 0}} *)
```

These make a hexagon shape with `ListPlot`:

```
ListPlot[hexpoints, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

The `pts` function in the OP is used to generate the grid on which the pattern repeats.

```
gridpts = pts[3, 2];
```

We can then translate the hexagon points to each point in the grid:

```
hexlattice = 
 TranslationTransform[# - hexpoints[[1]]][hexpoints] & /@ gridpts

ListPlot[hexlattice, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: ´´´hexlattice = 
 TranslationTransform[# - hexpoints[[1]]][hexpoints] & /@ gridpts´´´ could you explain what is happening in this line? And how do rotate this set of points around an arbitrary axis?

Comment: @LucasLopes `TranslationTransform[v]` returns a function that can translate points by a vector v. So for each point `#` in gridpts, we first call `TranslationFransform` with the vector `#-hexpoints[[1]]` (I arbitrarily picked the first point in hexpoints - you could pick any of them); then apply that transform function to all of the hexpoints. Another way to write that line is `Table[TranslationTransform[pt - hexpoints[[1]]][hexpoints], {pt, 
  gridpts}]`

Comment: @LucasLopes I think you should open a new question for rotation of points. Cheers

Comment: Is there any way to group hexlattice in {{0,0},{1,0},.....} ? Actually is grouped by each hexagon. In the case with pts[1,1] you get {{{},...,{}},{{},.....,{}},....8 times}.

Comment: I tried Flatten[TranslationTransform[# - hexpointss[[6]]][hexpointss] & /@ 
  ptss[1, 1], 1] it works well